# Two identical classes in the same jar file

Tags: java, jar, jaxb

I have a jar file - it happens to be generated from an XML schema using JAXB.

I have just noticed that in the same path inside that jar, I have 2 classes with the exact same name. As a matter of fact, if I unzip the jar using 7-zip, Windows asks me whether I want to replace file "blah.class" with "blah.class".

How can this be possible? Both from a Java perspective and from a filesystem perspective? Does the zip format allow for this? I tried to google around but to no avail.

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, zip does allow 2 files with the same fully qualified name.

The ant jar reference page states:

> Please note that the zip format allows multiple files of the same fully-qualified name to exist within a single archive. This has been documented as causing various problems for unsuspecting users. If you wish to avoid this behavior you must set the duplicate attribute to a value other than its default, "add".

Java would then pick the first one from the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar issues when including multiple implementations of the same interfaces in the same build.  If you find it necessary to do this, and are using Maven, you can use exclude tags to remove one of the implementations from the produced jar file.